# Aligning/floating my nav bar to the right

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm currently attempting to align my nav bar to the right, but it's stubbornly sticking to the left and I don't know what to do. I feel like I've tried everything - text-align, float, etc. I also have HTML5 CSS reset included, if that makes a difference.

Can someone look at my code and let me know if there may be some reason that these nav items won't move to the other side? I'm really frustrated. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="company.html">Company</a></li>
  <li><a href="team.html">Management Team</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
  body {font: normal 300 .8em 'Open Sans', sans-serif; overflow-x: hidden;}
  ul {text-align: right; width: 100%; background-color: #999; height: 20px; padding-  left: 150px;}
  li {float: left;}
  ul a {color: white; padding: 0 10px; text-decoration: none;}
  ul a:hover {color: #333;}
```

NOTE: This is the hacky way that I just fixed it

```
ul {text-align: right; width: 100%; background-color: #999; height: 20px; **padding-left: 750px;**}
```

however, I'm not sure that that is a very good way to do so...

Comment: Can you duplicate your problem on a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qZ7Tr/

Comment: If one of these answers fixes your problem please select one as the correct answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qZ7Tr/10/

Answer (score 7):

One, admittedly quite stupid solution (but it works), is to float list items to the right and then just reverse their order in HTML. Like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="team.html">Management Team</a></li>
  <li><a href="company.html">Company</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
</ul>

body {font: normal 300 .8em 'Open Sans', sans-serif; overflow-x: hidden;}
ul {text-align: right; width: 100%; background-color: #999; height: 20px;}
li {float: right;}
ul a {color: white; padding: 0 10px; text-decoration: none;}
ul a:hover {color: #333;}
```

[here is the JSFiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/w9ncR/3/)

Comment: Thanks, @TildalWave! I did think of this and yes, it does work well.

Comment: For display property the values "inline-table", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values. "inline" has been supported for quite a while.

Answer (score 5):

This is easy

http://jsfiddle.net/qZ7Tr/10/

change `li float` to `display:inline;`

```
body {
    font: normal 300 .8em'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
ul {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #999;
    height: 20px;
}
li {
    display:inline;
}
ul a {
    color: white;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in the CSS:

```
ul {text-align: right; width: 100%; background-color: #999; height: 20px; padding-left: 150px;}
```

To this:

```
ul {float: right; background-color: #999; height: 20px; padding-left: 150px;}
```

The problem is your original code was setting the width to 100%.  So it was stretching across the screen. `text-align` would not float the inner `<li>` elements to the right. So the only way to achieve it going right is to get rid of the `width: 100%;` and set a `float: right;`

If you want a grey box across the page, then wrap the `<ul>` in a `<div>` that has the `background-color: #999;` and the `width:100%`.  Only way to go.

Here is the HTML file I created to demonstrate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
body {font: normal 300 .8em 'Open Sans', sans-serif; overflow-x: hidden;}
  ul {float: right; background-color: #999; height: 20px; padding-left: 150px;}
  li {float: left;}
  ul a {color: white; padding: 0 10px; text-decoration: none;}
  ul a:hover {color: #333;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="company.html">Company</a></li>

    <li><a href="team.html">Management Team</a></li>

    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Additional test HTML file to show the `<div>` wrapper concept. It works for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">

<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        font: normal 300 .8em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    div
    {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #999;
    }

    ul
    {
        float: right;
        background-color: #999;
        height: 20px;
        padding- left: 150px;
    }

    li { float: left; }

    ul a
    {
        color: white;
        padding: 0 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul a:hover { color: #333; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

      <li><a href="company.html">Company</a></li>

      <li><a href="team.html">Management Team</a></li>

      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @JakeGould, the problem I'm seeing though is that I do want it to span with width of the browser at 100%, but wrapping the <ul> in a <div> tag and setting that to width: 100% and background color: #999 doesn't produce that, which I think is because setting width to 100% is just saying be as wide as that the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest code bellow it make easy to apply style:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="company.html">Company</a></li>
      <li><a href="team.html">Management Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font: normal 300 .8em 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #999;    
    height: 20px; 
}
 ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
}
ul li {
      float: left;
}
ul li a {color: white; 
    padding: 0 10px; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
 ul li a:hover {
      color: #333;
}
```

View code snipped http://jsfiddle.net/sophy/eRLtw/

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {float:right;}
```

Don't give the ul a width and you'll get exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you ever sorted this, but could try this...

```
ul {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:right;
}
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Then style you li's however you need with padding etc.

Might do the trick without worrying about floats.

Dan